# Margins for tcolorbox subtitle position

Tags: tcolorbox

I'd like to have the same margins in the subtitle than in the title frame of my tcolorbox.

For setting the margin in the titleframe, I've used `lefttitle=0mm`, but I haven't found anything related for the subtitle style.
In the MWE, I'd like to have the "Subtitle Frame" align the same way as the Title Frame.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Title Frame,
    lefttitle=0mm,
    %left=0mm, % flushes left everything : subtitle and its contents
    colback=red!5!white,
    colframe=red!75!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries]
    This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
    \tcbsubtitle[before skip=\baselineskip, 
        halign=left, % does not work
        lefttitle=0mm, % does not work either
        ]%
    {Subtitle Frame (margin to be set to 0mm)}
    Further text.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

The following code reduces well the margin of the title frame, but not the one of the subtitle.
[image: MWE output]

I've tried by setting a tcolorbox without any content (nor title), and 2 subtitles, but it displays me an empty space before the 1st subtitle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subtitle is a tcolorbox within the main tcolorbox, with the `oversize` property set to extend the new tcolorbox to the width of the original box (see the [package manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) on page 45). However, apparently `oversize` does not take `lefttitle` into account.

A solution is to set the left margin of the subtitle to 0mm and shift the subtitle bar to the left by 5mm (4mm margin and 1mm boxsep) and accordingly increase the size of the bar on the right by 4mm (I would expect this to be also 5mm but that is too much, I don't know why).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Title Frame,
    lefttitle=0mm,
    %left=0mm, % flushes left everything : subtitle and its contents
    colback=red!5!white,
    colframe=red!75!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    subtitle style={left=0mm,enlarge left by=-5mm,grow to right by=4mm}
    ]
    This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
    \tcbsubtitle[before skip=\baselineskip]%
    {Subtitle Frame (margin to be set to 0mm)}
    Further text.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that the settings are done with the key `subtitle style` in the main tcolorbox, resulting in the settings being applied to all subtitles in the same box (in case there is more than 1 subtitle). You can also apply the settings to individual subtitles by providing them as options to `\tcbsubtitle`.

Comment: Does the trick, thanks !